# Regex Positive lookahead get first occurrence

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I Have String like this, and I want capture characters between `.html` and the first slash

`http://example.org/some-path/some-title-in-1978.html`

This part `some-title-in-1978`, for that I came up with this regex:

`/\/.+?(?=\.html)/` and result are not what i want, it's like this:

`//domain.org/some-path/some-title-in-1978`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
[^/]+(?=\.html)
```

https://regex101.com/r/wep2Im/1

`[^/]+` - matches all characters that are followed by `.html` except *forward slash*

Comment: nice solution :)